# Select text with win32api keybd_event

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard

I'm trying to create a method to select text content of a notepad file using the following keys combination: CTRL+END then SHIFT+HOME

I have the following code to press, hold and release a sequence of keys:

```py
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import time

def keyboard_press_hold_release(*keys):
    for k in keys:
        win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[k], 0, 0, 0)
        time.sleep(.05)
    for k in keys:
        win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[k], 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        time.sleep(.1)
```

and call it to combine CTRL+END and SHIFT+HOME:

```py
keyboard_press_hold_release('ctrl', 'end')
keyboard_press_hold_release('shift', 'home')
```

As result the CTRL+END command is working but the SHIFT+HOME don't select the text, just move the cursor to the begin of line.

What is wrong?

Comment: Don't use `keybd_event`. It's documentation makes it very clear that the correct API for input faking is `SendInput`. Don't fake input though. Use UI Automation.

Comment: Btw, Ctrl+A is a shortcut for that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you have any suggestion of UI Automation lib?

Comment: @ipaleka, the real use of this solution will not be the notpad, but another application that doesn't supports the Ctrl+A behavior.

Comment: Ok. Another btw: you need `Ctrl + Shift + Home` to select all the text after reaching the end with `Ctrl + End`. Tho it misses explaining why your **line** isn't selected...

Comment: If the real use is a different application then can you be sure it won't block input faking. That's usually what happens.

Comment: Ctrl+A is supported by any standard edit control

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module for this purpose. Here is an example:

```
import keyboard
import time

time.sleep(5)     #You need some wait to switch to your window after executing

keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+end")
keyboard.press_and_release("shift+home")
```

If <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> doesn't work for you than you can use select the whole text in a single click using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

```
keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+a")
```

Comment: I got the same behavior. Tks for your try.